# Why the term "countable"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

In my computer science theory class, we are discussing the concept of *countability*.

I understand the concept, but the choice to use the **word** countability seems absolutely unintuitive to me. Why was it chosen? How can I count *anything* that is infinite? Wasn't there any other term that could be more descriptive of the nature of a set are trying to convey?

Comment: Countable in the sense that there is an algorithm to list the members of the set, and therefore each member is eventually counted.

Comment: The term seems perfect to me. What's the biggest number that can be counted to?

Comment: @NickR ah so I was under the assumption it had to be an algorithm only mapping natural numbers to items in the set, but is the broader idea that no algorithm can ever be used to create the set?

Comment: @C.B. That's basically the same thing.  The algorithm lists a first element, then a second, etc..  So you are indexing the elements with the natural numbers.

Comment: @NickR so the reason why a random number generator can never exist rings clear - if it were truly random, we would be able to create $R^n$ ?

Comment: @C.B. No algorithm will ever *create the set* since it can never complete its execution, unless the set is finite.

Comment: Please don't use math mode (`$` signs) for emphasis; use `*` instead (`*emphasis*` gives *emphasis*).  In titles, avoid emphasis altogether.

Comment: @NickR No algorithm will ever count the set of turing machines that do not halt; but that set is clearly countable, since the set of all turing machines is itself countable.

Comment: @ChasBrown That's very true, but perhaps a bit too subtle (and clever) and may confuse the OP further.  Excellent point though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An infinite set is countable if there's a way to start counting its elements such that, although you might never finish the count, each element will eventually be counted.

What is counting? It is making a bijection between a set of numbers and a set of things. When you point towards a collection of objects and say "1, 2, 3, ..." you are assigning a natural number to each object. In that sense counting an infinite set is the same as giving a bijection between that and $\mathbb{N}$, and a countable set is one such that this is possible.

Comment: That's a great explanation behind the term, but how then can we say that the number of elements in it, although it's countable, is not the same than one that isn't?

Comment: @C.B. If one accepts the existence of an infinite set such as $ \mathbb N $, then can assign a * number * to its size (cardinality).  It is not a finite number.  In the case of the natural numbers, it is the *smallest* infinite cardinal, which we name $ \aleph_0 $ .

Comment: Two sets having the same size means there's a bijection between them. Suppose $S$ is countable, so there's a bijection between $S$ and $\mathbb{N}$. Then if $T$ is countable, there's also a bijection between $T$ and $\mathbb{N}$, so we can construct a bijection between $S$ and $T$, i.e. $T$ and $S$ have the same size. Conversely, if $T$ and $S$ have the same size, we can construct a bijection between $T$ and $\mathbb{N}$, so $T$ is countable. So if $S$ is countable, it has the same size as another set $T$ if and only if $T$ is also countable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the term is really self explanatory, since we are talking about sets X that either are finite, perfectly countable, or that there exists a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ which is giving us a "natural" enumeration of something, when we write

$$f(1) = x_{1}, f(2) = x_{},...,f(n)= x_{n},...$$

We should have then $X = \lbrace x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n},...\rbrace$.

Answer (score 0):

When you count things, you set up a map to the integers. That is, you pick a first object, then a second one, then a third etc. A set is countable, then, if there is a way of assigning a nice order to the elements, so that for any given element you could count up to it.

On the other hand, sets are uncountable if, no matter how you started counting, there would be elements that you would never get to, no matter how long you kept going. In order to get everything, you would need to use a process other than 'find the next one'.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical usage "$A$ is a countable set" doesn't imply there is an *algorithm* which counts each element, one after another. It instead asserts that there exists an (injective) function $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb N$; the distinction will become clearer when you study things like the Halting Problem.

Finite sets are of course countable; and an infinite set may also be countable (e.g., the set of all even naturals).

The term "countable" is probably best understood in the context of sets, such as $\mathbb R$, for which no such function exists; these sets are "uncountable".

Answer (score 0):

The idea is not that you can count the entire infinite collection. But that you can index the collection so that every element can be counted after a finite number of steps.

Meaning there is an element counted the first step, $a_1$ then the second step, $a_2$ and so on. And each element has a unique index which only finitely many previous indices before we arrive it. This is exactly the meaning of "There is an injection from the set into the natural numbers".

We don't count the set, we essentially say that we can index the set in a way that every element is counted after just a finite number of steps.